# HTML validations from javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<input type="text" id="newFname" pattern="^[a-zA-z0-9 _-]{2,}$" required placeholder="First Name" />

<input type="text" id="newLname" pattern="^[a-zA-z0-9 _-]{2,}$" required placeholder="Last Name"/>
```

Is it possible to disable html validation on second input without modifying **pattern** or **required** attributes?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the only way to disable html validation is to modify those attributes.

Comment: What is the reason you would want to disable validation and yet leave these attributes there? I'm curious.

Comment: I just thought that it would be easier if I can achieve it by changing some one attribute instead of two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you could do, put the inputs in separate forms and add the `novalidate` attribute to the second form.

Check [this](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_novalidate.asp) page for more information.